# detect collision of animated elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have two elements animating. The first is animating from top to bottom. While the second element is animating from left to right. How can i detect when these elements collide? I have created a sample http://jsfiddle.net/6XQ4Q/3/

```
$(".container, .pool").height(800);

setInterval(function () {
    randomWave();
}, 3000);



function randomWave() {
    var wave = $(".wave");
    var waveItem = wave.find(".waveItem");
    var number = waveItem.length;
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
    waveItem.removeClass("active");
    waveItem.eq(random).addClass("active");

    if ((waveItem.eq(random).hasClass("right"))) {

        $(".kid").animate({
            left: "-=50"
        });
    }


    if ((waveItem.eq(random).hasClass("left"))) {

        $(".kid").animate({
            left: "+=50"
        });
    }
}


setInterval(function () {
    droppingCoin();
}, 6000);


function droppingCoin() {

    //var newq = makeNewPosition();         

    $(".coin").animate({
        top: 800,
        opacity: "toggle"
    }, 5000, "linear", function () {
        $(this).css({
            top: "-15px"
        }).show();

    });


}
```

Comment: Try this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/e-smart-hittest-jquery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```js
var delta = ($(".coin").width() + $(".kid").width()) * 0.5 ;
var x1 = $(".coin").offset().left,
    y1 = $(".coin").offset().top,
    x2 = $(".kid").offset().left,
    y2 = $(".kid").offset().top;

if (x1 >= x2 - delta && x1 <= x2 + delta &&
    y1 >= y2 - delta && y1 <= y2 + delta)
{
    $(".kid").css({"background": "blue"}); // HIT!
} else {
    $(".kid").css({"background": "red"}); // No hit...
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6XQ4Q/4/)

EDIT: [A more accurate version](http://jsfiddle.net/6XQ4Q/5/):

```
var r1 = $(".coin").width() / 2,      // "Radius" of .coin
    x1 = $(".coin").offset().left,    // x position
    y1 = $(".coin").offset().top,     // y position
    r2 = $(".kid").width() / 2,       // "Radius" of .kid
    x2 = $(".kid").offset().left,     // x position
    y2 = $(".kid").offset().top,      // y position
    dx = x2 - x1,                     // Difference in horizontal position
    dy = y2 - y1,                     // Difference in vertical position
    L = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy), // Distance between
    step = r1 + r2 - L;               // Amount of overlap
if(step > 0) {                        // There's a collision if step > 0
    $(".kid").css({"background": "blue"});
} else {
    $(".kid").css({"background": "red"});
}
```

[image: figure 1]

Comment: Yes it does... could you explain the logic?

Comment: Sure! We store the coordinates of the coin and the kid, then we check if they're equal. Of course, they're only equal if both divs are in the very same pixel, so we bracket the comparison with the sum of the "radius" of the coin and the kid. This way the collision will happen even if only the edges of the coin and the kid are touching. I can draw a graph of this, if it helps?